# How to specify width and height when loading external swf file?

Tags: actionscript, flash, size, external

I am trying to load an external swf file. The swf width and height is small and I want to enlarge it when loading it. (My scene has large width and height). My current code could load the file but I am not sure how to enlarge the swf width and height. I would appreciate if anyone can help me about it...Thanks

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("index.swf");
var loader:Loader = new Loader()
loader.load(request);

addChild(loader);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Loader class](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Loader.html#propertySummary) is a DisplayObject (which is how you can add it to the stage). You should be able to just set the width and height of your loader:

```
loader.width = 50;
loader.height = 50;
```

UPDATED: Make sure to read the comments about width vs. scaleX and being loaded or on the stage.

Comment: Ty sunetos, for some reasons, when I added your code before addChild(loader) and tested the movie, it rendered blank . However, if I took your code out, it worked again..any idea why??Thanks and +1..

Comment: Have you changed the value from 50 to a greater one? Maybe you're only seeing a blank part of the loaded movieclip.

Comment: Building on jdecuyper's comment, you could always use loader.scaleX and scaleY instead of setting width and height directly.

Comment: If that's not working, then we might need to see more of your code to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: thx sunetos...scaleX and scaleY works but was wondering why width and height don't..

Comment: I have run into issues in the past with setting width and height on objects that are not fully initialized/added to the stage yet. If you want to set them explicitly, you might need to attach an event handler for ADDED_TO_STAGE or LOADED on the loader and then set the width and height.